# How to occupy free space in Eclipse UI?

Tags: java, layout, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to put some view to the bottom part (1) of layout, then put another view to the left part of remaining space (2)?

The entire area is 3.

[image]

Comment: When you reference view, do you mean actual text editors or windows such as Console, package explorer, and so on? I have replicated what you have described with Package Explorer in 2, and Console in 1, with the negative space being text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at [`IPageLayout` JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPageLayout.html). It should be set up in your perspective's `IPerspectiveFactory.createInitialLayout(IPageLayout)`. Slightly modifying the example given there:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    // Get the editor area.
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();

    // Bottom left: Outline view and Property Sheet view
    IFolderLayout bottom = layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 
        0.25f, editorArea);
    bottom.addView(IPageLayout.ID_OUTLINE);

    // Top left: Project Explorer view and Bookmarks view placeholder
    IFolderLayout topLeft = layout.createFolder("topLeft", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f,
        editorArea);
    topLeft.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
    topLeft.addPlaceholder(IPageLayout.ID_BOOKMARKS);
}
```